# To pick some fields out of a const Omit/Pick/Exclude alike

Tags: typescript

I came across a use case when I need to pick certain values out of a const and then to export them depending on a certain condition.
The following snippet illustrates my case:

```
type ABC = { a: string; b: string; c: string };
const abc: ABC = { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" };
type AB = Exclude<ABC, "c">;
type C = Exclude<ABC, "a" | "b">;
const ab: AB = abc;
const c: C = abc;
let condition = false;
export const MY_CONST = condition ? ab : c;
console.log(ab);
```

Is there any way to cut the fields that do not exist in the type AB, but by assigning to a variable of type AB a variable with the type ABC?

Comment: Sidenote: Exclude is for unions `Exclude<ABC, "c">` -> `Omit<ABC, "c">` Omit is to remove properties from an object.

Answer (score 0):

TS types only exist at compile type, they have no effect on the code, once it's compiled.

You'll have to explicitly pick/omit properties from am object

```
function omit<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Omit<T, K> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).filter(kv => !keys.includes(kv[0] as any))
    ) as Omit<T, K>;
}

function pick<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        keys.filter(key => key in obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]])
    ) as Pick<T, K>;
}

type ABC = { a: string; b: string; c: string };

const abc: ABC = { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" };
const ab = omit(abc, "c");
console.log(ab);

const c = omit(abc, "a", "b");
console.log(c);
```